# glDrawElements doesn't render all the points

Tags: c++, opengl

In the first place, I'm rendering a point cloud with OpenGL.

```
// The object pointCloud wraps some raw data in different buffers.

// At this point, everything has been allocated, filled and enabled.

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, pointCloud->count());
```

This works just fine.

However, I need to render a mesh instead of just points. To achieve that, the most obvious way seems to be using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and glDrawElements with the good array of indices.

So I start by transforming my current code by something that should render the exact same thing.

```
// Creates a set of indices of all the points, in their natural order
std::vector<GLuint> indices;
indices.resize(pointCloud->count());
for (GLuint i = 0; i < pointCloud->count(); i++)
    indices[i] = i;

// Populates the element array buffer with the indices  
GLuint ebo = -1;
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Should draw the exact same thing as the previous example
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

But it doesn't work right. It's rendering something that seems to be only the first quarter of the points.
If I mess with the indices range by making it 2 or 4 times smaller, the same points are displayed. If it's 8 times smaller, only the first half of them is.
If I fill it with only even indices, one half of the same set of points is shown.
If I start it at the half of the set, nothing is shown.

There's obviously something that I'm missing about how glDrawElement behaves in comparison to glDrawArrays.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size passed as the second argument to `glBufferData()` is in bytes. The posted code passes the number of indices instead. The call needs to be:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I was too blind to look at the right place !